# R code to merge survey data (incl. GPS) with temperature data by closest lon lat, and 12 months before survey month (raster package?)

Tags: r, merge, geospatial, latitude-longitude, raster

in R, I want to merge **dhs survey data** which **includes the GPS location** of the interviewee with **temperature data** *air.mon.mean.v501.nc* (Terrestrial Air Temperature: 1900-2017 Gridded Monthly Time Series) (https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html).

---

So far:
My **survey dataset** (called **"***kids.dta"***)** contains one observation per interviewee. Besides others, one variable is "*lon*", one is "*lat*", one is "*interview_month*", "*interview_year*".
latitude values range from -90 to 90; longitude values range from -180 to 180;

e.g. lat 27.41974, lon 87.60922, interview_month 12, interview_year 2001

With the following R code, the **temperature data** follows the same coordinate grid as the survey data.

open_air_brick <- brick("air.mon.mean.v501.nc", var="air")

open_air <- rotate(open_air_brick)

Please note: **lat and lon are rounded** for the temperature data:
e.g. lat 27.5, lon 87.5 (!)

---

---

What I want:
I want to have a final dataset with the **survey data** and the corresponding **monthly temperature** of the **year leading up to the month of survey** (month of survey, and the 12 months before) for each observation **based on their location** (lon / lat).

---

---

What I guess I need to do:

1. find **closest lon / lat** in the temperature data for every observation in the survey data (e.g. lat 27.41974 is nearest to lat 27.5), and assign it to the survey data
2. **merge** survey data with temperature data based on prior assigned closest lon and lat, and ONLY extract temperature data for the month of survey and 12 months before the survey.

---

I have honestly no clue how to do it.
So far, I have been working with the R **Raster package**.

**If someone has ***any idea or hint***, I will be so grateful!**

Comment: Of course, no need to solve the whole issue but, please, a hint would be so nice!

Comment: Sounds similar to this taxi cab problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160698/how-to-join-location-data-lat-lon/65160918#65160918