# Relate lat and long of two dataframes where coordinates are not exactly the same (shortest distance)

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

See I have two dataframes, both with lat and long. My idea is to compare lat and long of both dataframes. If you see, for example, we have for `Market1` of dataframe `x`, latitude equal to `-22.89290` and longitude equal to `-48.45048`, which is similar (not equal) to the third line of dataframe `y`, which has a latitude of `-22.89287` and a longitude of `-48.45075`. You can see that this happens in the other `Markets`. Note that the first 5 numbers are the same, in this case it was `-22.892` for lat and `-48.450` for long. Therefore, if they are the same, insert the names of the `Marketname` column of the dataframe `x` into the `Marketname` column of the dataframe `y`, as shown in `Expected output`.

```
x<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-22.8928950233225, -22.929618895716, 
-22.8773751675936), Longitude = c(-48.4504779883472, -48.4515412645053, 
-48.4364903609011), Marketname = c("Market1", "Market2", 
"Market3")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

> x
   Latitude Longitude Marketname
1 -22.89290 -48.45048    Market1
2 -22.92962 -48.45154    Market2
3 -22.87738 -48.43649    Market3


y<- structure(list(lat = c(-22.8715263, -22.8774825, -22.8928723, 
-22.9295906), lng = c(-48.440335, -48.4364964, -48.4507477, -48.4516264
), Marketname = c("Market0","0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

 > y   
        lat       lng Marketname
1 -22.87153 -48.44033    Market0
2 -22.87748 -48.43650          0
3 -22.89287 -48.45075          0
4 -22.92959 -48.45163          0
```

**Expected output**

```
 > y   
            lat       lng Marketname
    1 -22.87153 -48.44033    Market0
    2 -22.87748 -48.43650    Market3
    3 -22.89287 -48.45075    Market1      
    4 -22.92959 -48.45163    Market2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join location data (lat,lon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160698/how-to-join-location-data-lat-lon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to need the shortest distance to each market based on geocoordinates on an ellipsoid, you should use something like `geosphere::distGeo`. To compare each coordinat of `y` with each of `x` we may `Vectorize` the function and use an `outer` approach. Note, that we don't want the first column, so we remove first element of the sequence [1,...n] `seq_len(nrow(y))[-1]`.

```
f <- Vectorize(\(i, j) geosphere::distGeo(y[i, 2:1], x[j, 2:1]))
u <- outer(seq_len(nrow(y))[-1], seq_len(nrow(x)), f) |> apply(1, which.min)
u
# [1] 3 1 2
```

Insert into `x` like so:

```
y[-1, 3] <- x[u, 3]
y
#         lat       lng Marketname
# 1 -22.87153 -48.44033    Market0
# 2 -22.87748 -48.43650    Market3
# 3 -22.89287 -48.45075    Market1
# 4 -22.92959 -48.45163    Market2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I insert this information in `y`, to get the output table that I inserted in the question?

Comment: @CarloSoares See update, also found a better solution.

Comment: Thanks so much @jay.sf, this is a better solution!